# In Jmeter how to create a json array files with respective to their location

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, jsr223

In Jmeter need help to create a json file with array/list of values with respective to their location(nested loop and group by location).

I have a scenario to create a JSON file using a csv. I used JMeter dummy sampler to create them but I couldn’t figure out on how to create json in nested loop(put all the GTIN,approved,erp_stock_RFID_stock as a list/array in json with respective to location). How do I handle this? Need some help as I am new to jmeter and jsr223? Providing sample csv and required json format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPsfp.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNmym.png)

Tried using Beanshell and JSR223 sampler, but couldnt get what is required.
Need to create 350 json files.

Answer (score 0):

At least I'm not able to figure out what needs to be done and what is the relationship between the data in CSV and the JSON payload, especially given you [posted text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

So I can only suggest using [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class (or [StreamingJsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/json/StreamingJsonBuilder.html) if data is large) for creating the JSON.

The data from the CSV file can be read using either [built-in Groovy GDK](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) functions like:

```
String text =  new File('test.csv').text
```

or

```
List<String> lines = new File('test.csv').readLines()
```

or you can use external libraries like [GroovyCSV](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html#_builders)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)